# How do I chnage the height/width of a previously created window on relaunch?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I opened a named, singleton window previously with code that set the bounds to `{ width: 1200, height: 600 }`. I then changed my code and updated the app in Chrome but when it opens, it continues to use the previous size! The only way to get it to use a different size is to name it something else. How would I use the same name but change the dimensions?

**First version used**

```
var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
var width = 1200;
var height = 600;

//Create the app window
chrome.app.window.create(
    'options.html',
    {
        frame: "none",
        bounds:
        {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
            top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
        },
        id: "optionsWindow",
        singleton: true
    }
);
```

**Updated verions of my app used:**

```
var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
var width = 700;
var height = 600;

//Create the app window
chrome.app.window.create(
    'options.html',
    {
        frame: "none",
        bounds:
        {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
            top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
        },
        id: "optionsWindow",
        singleton: true
    }
);
```

In both cases, its' 1200 pixels wide. Only if I change the name to `"optionsWindow2"` does it show up as the new size.

**More Info**

If I pass a callback to the `create` function and try to use the AppWindow form there, it says it's null and was not opened by the `chrome.app.window`! If I create a new, never before created window (e.g. `optionsWindow3`, then the callback does return a valid AppWindow! Why is this?

Comment: Please file a crbug.com bug with a concise code sample that demonstrates the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To change the size, you must change the ID.

The result you are seeing is by design. If you specify an ID for a window then the bounds you offer are only used once, for the initial window creation. The user's window bounds are then cached and reused when you launch again with the same ID.